# converting str to int in list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I have a list with years as strings but there are few missing years which are represented as empty strings.

I am trying to convert those strings to integers and skip the values which can't be converted using list comprehension and try and except clause?

```
birth_years = ['1993','1994', '' ,'1996', '1997', '', '2000', '2002']
```

I tried this code but it's not working.

```
try:
    converted_years = [int(year) for year  in birth_years]
except ValueError:
    pass

required output:
converted_years = ['1993','1994','1996', '1997', '2000', '2002']
```

Comment: [int(year) for year  in birth_years if year]

Comment: @Chris_Rands How can I use try and except clause with pass statement to achieve this?

Comment: You can either use a list comprehension or a `try ... except`. Not both.

Comment: You can't use a try-except in a comprehension, you could do it in a regular for loop

Comment: Of course you could create a separate function that perform the try-except and then call that in the comprehension but I don't see any point (for this simple example at least)

Comment: @Chris_Rands can you tell me how to do that for learning purpose?

Comment: write a function like `def my_f: try: return int(year); except ValueError: pass` then in the comprehension `[my_f(year) for year in birth_years if my_f(year) ]` (the pass means the fasly None is returned when the error is encountered, not this isn't the most efficient to call the function twice)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`[int(year) for year in birth_years if year.isdigit()]`

Answer (score 2):

```
converted_years = [int(year) for year in birth_years if year]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
converted_years = [int(x) for x in birth_years if x.isdigit()]
```