# How to turn str numbers into int type in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, casting, int

I am a newbie in python/python3 here, trying to figure out the following...

I have a list containing the following data:

```
datalist = ['1','2','abc','def','a234','b456']

print(type(new_datalist[0]))

print(type(new_datalist[1]))

<class 'str'>

<class 'str'>
```

**Is there a way to improvise the datalist to make the numbers in the list be converted into an int from its current str type ?**

***Desired outcome:***

```
new_datalist = []

print(new_datalist)

[1, 2 ,'abc','def','a234','b456']


print(type(new_datalist[0]))

print(type(new_datalist[1]))

<class 'int'>

<class 'int'>
```

Comment: Please format your code and question properly. Check out the [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct).

Comment: Please show what you’ve tried so far and where you are stuck.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [converting str to int in list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51745416/converting-str-to-int-in-list-comprehension)

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
d = [int(i) if i.isnumeric() else i for i in datalist]
print(d)
```

```
[1, 2 ,'abc','def','a234','b456']
```

See the types -

```
[type(i) for i in d]
```

```
[int, int, str, str, str, str]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function that converts to int where possible:

```
def int_or_str(s):
    "try to convert to int, but return string if it fails"
    try:
        return int(s)
    except ValueError:
        return s

new_datalist = [int_or_str(s) for s in datalist]
```

or if you prefer a one-liner you would have to do something like this to allow for the possibility of negative numbers:

```
new_datalist = [int(s)  
                if s.isnumeric() or (s and s[0] == '-' and s[1:].isnumeric())
                else s
                for s in datalist]
```

You can also use regular expressions:

```
import re

new_datalist = [int(s) if re.match('-?\d+$', s) else s for s in datalist]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension to elegantly solve your problem.

```py
datalist = [int(data) if data.isdigit() else data for data in datalist]
```